# How would you use @font-face work if you have multiple font types? For example Josefin Slab SemiBold and Josefin Slab Bold, etc

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

Secondly if I have a font converter tool that creates the font to a different font type otf, ttf etc. and I try and install the font into my font folder on my laptop (which it doesn't register) will it work if I load into an FTP with @font-face.

So the questions come down to do I have to write the font-face differently for different types or is there a way I can combine them.

Comment: There are various aspects to fonts that all map to individual `@font-face` descriptors, so you have to be careful which faces and which files you assign.

Comment: Hey @BlockClock, thanks for the tip. Could you please provide more information. Preferably in code format so I have an idea as to what it is you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine all the different font formats into one `@font-face`. Here's an example:

```
@font-face{ 
  font-family: 'font-name';
  src: url('example-font.eot');
  src: url('example-font.eot?iefix') format('eot'),
    url('example-font.woff') format('woff'),
    url('example-font.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('example-font.svg#webfont') format('svg');
}
```

Comment: hey @user3394498, thank you the tip. I had to use a font-converter to get the other font types. However when I load them in they don't seem to be picked up even with the code. Secondly what about the other font "weight" file i.e. Josefin Slab Bold and Josefin Slab SemiBold how would I write this out in font-face

Comment: This addresses the issue of font *formats*. The question is about *typefaces* of a font (called “types” in the question).

Answer (score 0):

There are two different approaches to the issue of using more than one typeface of a font:

1) Specify each typeface in a `@font-face` declaration, using the same `font-family` value but different `font-style`, `font-weight`, or (in principle) `font-variant`.

2) Specify each typeface as if it were a font family, using a distinctive name for each typeface as the `font-family` value. Do not set `font-style`, `font-weight`, or `font-variant`.

Method 1 is more logical, whereas method 2 is what some font generators use, so you may need to edit the CSS code they generate if you wish to use method 1.

Method 1 is compatible with default CSS settings that many elements have. For example, heading elements have `font-weight: bold` by default.